# Autowiring of bean not working context:component scan

Tags: java, spring

Playing around with an archetype.  I have a test class which autowires an JPARepository

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:appContext-test.xml")
@Transactional
public class PersonRepositoryTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonRepositoryTest.class);

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;
```

My appContext-test.xml was working fine with this

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.mycompany.rd.misf.repository" />
```

But as I am trying to understand spring, I thought this may also work.  So I commented out the jpa:repositories tag and supplemented my component scan with this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.rd.misf.model,com.mycompany.rd.misf.repository" />
```

My repository is annotated with @Repository

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
    public List<Person> findByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName,
            String lastName);

    @Query("select p from Person p where p.firstName = :firstName or p.lastName = :lastName")
    public List<Person> findByFirstNameOrLastName(
            @Param("firstName") String firstName,
            @Param("lastName") String lastName);

    public Page<Person> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

But I am getting exceptions:

> Could not autowire field:
>   com.mycompany.rd.misf.repository.PersonRepository
>   com.mycompany.rd.misf.repository.PersonRepositoryTest.personRepository;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [com.mycompany.rd.misf.repository.PersonRepository] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Why would this not work?

I have set in my appContext-text.xml file.

> 

Any help appreciated.

Regards

i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Spring JPA documentation says the following about [`jpa:repositories`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.create-instances)

> [...] **Spring is instructed to scan**
>   `com.acme.repositories` **and all its subpackages for interfaces extending
>   Repository or one of its subinterfaces. For each interface found, the
>   infrastructure registers the persistence technology-specific
>   FactoryBean to create the appropriate proxies that handle invocations
>   of the query methods. Each bean is registered under a bean name that
>   is derived from the interface name, so an interface of UserRepository
>   would be registered under userRepository.** The base-package attribute
>   allows wildcards, so that you can define a pattern of scanned
>   packages.

So

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.mycompany.rd.misf.repository" />
```

scans that base package and all its sub packages for classes extending `Repository` which `JpaRepository` does and therefore your `PersonRepository` interface does so a bean is created.

This is behavior specific to JPA.

With

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.rd.misf.model,com.mycompany.rd.misf.repository" />
```

you're telling Spring to scan the specified package(s) and its(their) subpackages for components, types annotated with `@Component` and its specializations. If any annotated **classes** are found, Spring should create a bean definition for them.

In your case, it finds a specialization of `@Component`, `@Repository`, but it is an interface, so it doesn't register a bean definition. It is has absolutely no knowledge of JPA in this case.